# What is the total number of nodes generated by Depth-First Search

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

Assume: 'd' is the finite depth of a tree ; 'b' is a branching factor ; 'g' is the shallowest goal node.

From what I know, the worst-case is when the goal node is at the very last right-bottomed node in a tree. 
Thus, supposedly the total number of nodes generated is O(bg), right? 
However, my instructor told me it was wrong since the worst-case is when all the tree are explored except the subtree rooted at the goal node. 
He mentioned something about O(bd) - O(b(g-d)) .... *I'm not entirely sure*.

I don't really get what he means, so can somebody tell me which answer is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend drawing a tree, marking the nodes that are explored, and counting how many there are.

Your reasoning is correct if you use breadth first search because you will only have reached a depth of g for each branch (`O(b**g)` nodes explored in total).

Your instructor's reasoning is correct if you use depth first search because you reach a depth of d for all parts of the tree except the one with the goal (`O(b**d - b**(d-g))` nodes explored).

[image]

The goal is the green circle.

The blue nodes are explored.

The red nodes are not explored.

To count the number explored we count the total in the tree, and take away the red ones.

Depth = 2 = d

Goal at depth = 1 = g

Branching factor = b = 3

Note that I have called the total number of nodes in the tree `O(b**d)`.  Strictly speaking, the total is `b**d + b**(d-1) + b**(d-2) + ... + 1`, but this is `O(b**d)`.

Comment: Okay. I still don't understand why do we have to subtract the two results (b^d and b^(d-g)).

Comment: Ah, I see. Now I get it why we do have to subtract the two. Thanks for the clear explanation!